# Listen music in the background

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to know if it is possible to listen a podcast (or text-to-speech book) and play Apple Music in the background. If not possible, would be feasible to implement this in IOS?. As an alternative, I’m planning to buy an iPod and a second pair of headphones if this sounds tough.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to play two audio *sources* at once like from Podcasts and Music?

Comment: Basically, yes @Allan